# How to output a code stored in variable to code?

Tags: php, json, api

I am new to this but making some real good progres :-).

It is all in PHP, JSON.

I am stuck at this simple question and cannot find an answer anywhere on the web.

Here is my problem:

1. I have code stored inside the variable.
2. I want to output that code just below some other code and I want it to be interpreted.
3. Alternatively I want the code from the $variable to be runned in the middle of my code.

I have tried echo, print, var_dump etc. their output is human readable and I want it to be just runned in the middle of my code.

```
$variable='
$request[method1][0] = array();
$request[method1][0][var1] = 1;
$request[method1][0][var2] = 13;
$request[method1][0][var3] = nonrefundable;
$request[method1][0][var4] = 1;
$request[method1][0][var5] = 96;
$request[method1][0][var6] = "2019-02-12";
$request[method1][0][var7] = whole;'
```

needless to say it is exactly 6211 times longer

```
$request = array();
$request['authenticate'] = array();
$request['authenticate']['systemKey'] = 
$request['authenticate']['systemLogin'] = 
$request['authenticate']['lang'] = 'eng';
output ($variable)
```

I am looking for that 'output' function or some other method. Later on $request is encoded with 'json_encode'

I expect it to run as the code from the variable would be just pasted below.

Comment: To have a nice display of an array (such as $request), I recommande this **echo "<pre>".print_r($request, true)."</pre>"** . PS : use **echo** only for simple variable. For array/object, use print_r or var_dump (if from json, use **json_encode($json, true)**)

Comment: @MorganTartreau Why not `var_dump()`? print_r hides very useful informations from you. See e.g. https://3v4l.org/BpoDC

Comment: You are probably confusing having PHP code added dynamically that can run (something like `include`, `eval`) and content emitted to the client (`echo`, `var_dump`..). Can you tell us where this PHP code comes from? There can be security issues with executing code grabbed from somewhere else, and if it's not from the outside, using a function is much better

Comment: Looking for [eval()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)?

Comment: You probably want [eval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)

Comment: Unfortunately neither of those comments are useful. I want it to work as that code from the variable would be just pasted instead of variable.

Comment: If neither are helpful, you probably didn't try it properly, or provided confusing/incomplete informations in your question, try adding all relevant iformations as asked, plus what is the expected behaviour/output in precision ("runned in the middle of my code" and "would be just pasted below" -> where, server PHP or client JS?) , good luck!

Answer (score 0):

To display a variable in PHP, you have several options, each being more useful in certain contexts:

- `echo` (https://php.net/echo)
- `var_dump` (https://php.net/var_dump)
- `print_r` (https://php.net/print_r):

They are used the following way:

- `echo $variable;`
- `var_dump($variable);`
- `print_r($variable);`

If you wish to recover your result from a JavaScript script for example, you would encode it as JSON and then echo it:

```php
echo json_encode($variable);
```

Comment: Thank you for taking interest in my question. I do not want to display the variable in human readable format. But added below so it can be encoded in json. I want it to work as content of the variable would be pasted instead of variable. Is it at all possible ? or do I have to look for work around?

Comment: I don't understand why you don't just `echo` your $request['method'][0] for example. Or create your $variable as an array and then filling it with the content you want before echoing it...